# WEBVTT subtitles shown multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, video, subtitle

This is the WEBVTT:

```
WEBVTT FILE

1
00:10:21.125 --> 00:10:23.951
Test

2
00:10:25.080 --> 00:10:27.392
another
test

3
00:10:39.959 --> 00:10:42.676
Damn
```

This code is generated "on the fly". 
My `track` tag is as follows:

```
<track kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English" default></track>
```

I create a blob from a generated string, then a URL from the blob and link the `track` to the URL.

If the generated file has one subtitle - everything is just fine. Once a second subtitle added, the first one appears twice (one above the other) and the second appears once. With three subtitles the first one appears three times, the second twice and the third once.

What is this crap? Where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing the track element and generating a new one each time.